# Open an Unix executable (and authorization) from a swift file in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, unix

I  am trying to create a little application in Xcode to open an Unix Executable file from an application in mac os which is basically : Push Button -> Unix Executable file.
The ViewControler.swift code is:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func runButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Me/MyApplicationFolder/MyApplication/UnixExecutableFile", isDirectory: true) as URL

        let path = "/bin"
        let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
        configuration.arguments = [path]
        NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: url,
                                           configuration: configuration,
                                           completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
}
```

But when I push the button I have an error popup displaying:

> The application “MyApplication” does not have permission to open “UnixExecutableFile.”

And obviously, does not run the UnixExecutableFile.
But If I just go to /Users/Me/MyApplicationFolder/MyApplication/UnixExecutableFile and click the UnixExecutableFile icon, It just start normally.

What am I missing here? It is a info.plist thing?

Comment: So what are the open permissions of the executable?

Comment: Make sure you disable the Sandbox config. If you tend to use Sandbox app, you should check out some 3rd-party library that allows you to execute under sudo mode. Ex: SwiftCLI, STPrivilegedTask